# 3D Flood Fill using Java

Tags: java, 3d, flood-fill, jmonkeyengine

I am using the JMonkey Engine to create a 3D bounding box and then I'm trying to use smaller boxes to flood fill the bounding box. Unfortunately I can't find a 3D flood fill algorithm.

Does anyone know of a 3d flood fill algorithm or have any pseudo code or examples of this being done in any language?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will find something like that. Floodfill is somewhat bound to pixel based graphics, and that doesn't go along well with OpenGl / 3d.

If you have some kind of pixel concept for 3d, I think adapting a 2d algorithm shouldn't be rocket science. I just doubt anyone found it useful so far.

Perhaps something like [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) is worth further reading?